# How to allow a process to be shut down cleanly

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a process that I would like to be able to cleanly shut down from an external process. That is, I would like to give it a chance to clean up it's resources (save it's data etc.) before it dies.

`Process.CloseMainWindow` appears to be the ordinary way to go, except the process in question doesn't have any windows and I don't want to immediately call `Process.Kill` because I want to give it chance to clean up first (and a kill process command can't be intercepted by the target process).

So what is the best way to allow my process to be shut cleanly from another process?

I have control over both processes. The process to be shut does have a message loop (`Application.Run()`) so I would think there would be some message I could post through there.

I have read the [msdn article on terminating processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/terminating-a-process) and [this article about closing processes cleanly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/178893/how-to-terminate-an-application-cleanly-in-win32) however both mention methods that seem quite sophisticated despite the simplicity of what I am trying to achieve. Given that I have control over both processes I am hoping there's something a bit simpler that can be implemented cleanly in C#. Is there one?

The process to close is **not** a service, so can't do service stop.

Comment: @axlj Can you please explain what's confusing? That event won't work as that only happens if the app itself calls `Application.Exit()` (this has been tested)

Comment: If the process doesnt have a window you cannot use a standard windows message. If you have control over the other process, just use any IPC method to listen for the request to close from your other app. named pipes, sockets, wcf, create a hidden window and listen for a message, there are just so many ways, you could even poll a reg key (not recommended), however just pick an IPC method, and yeahaa

Comment: Also if its windowless, you could also make it a service, and just use standard start stop (if it doesnt need to intereact with the current user)

Comment: @TheGeneral Ok, if no one can come up with a solution particularly well suited to this problem I will just make IPC the answer.

Comment: @TheGeneral It's not a service.

Comment: it will take like minutes to do an hiden window, or IPC method, you will spend hours here, and i doubt you will find away to gracefully close a windowless app, well not that i can think of withouth coding for it in the receiving app

Comment: @TheGeneral The answer might end up being make a hidden window, but doesn't that have side effects? I need to assess the solutions and come up with the best one, I don't care if it takes a couple of hours.

Comment: At least in Windows 10, taskkill.exe will send `WM_CLOSE` to a message-only window, which is inherently hidden and exempt from broadcast messages. It enumerates message-only windows via `FindWindowEx` and maps them back to a process via `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.

Comment: A window is not the only way to deliver a notification to a process.  It is actually the awkward way to do it since you need the window handle.  You'd favor a more basic way with a number or a name.  As supported by a socket or a named pipe.

Comment: A window is the only generic way that allows clean shutdown from Task Manager, taskkill.exe, and other such utilities. Named kernel objects or sockets can only be used as a private channel between applications. If you're going to support a clean shutdown, you may as well do it in a generic way that will work when a user or script kills the program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a .NET message loop supports thread messages, or only window messages. If it supports thread messages, then the terminating app can use [`PostThreadMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx) to post a `WM_QUIT` message (or a custom message that the message loop can look for) to the main thread of the target process so it can stop its message loop and exit the app.

Otherwise, have the target app create a named kernel event object using [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) and then wait on the event, either by calling [`EventWaitHandle.WaitOne()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone) in a manual thread, or calling [`ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02x3daw5.aspx) to use a system-provided thread pool. When the event is signaled, you can notify the main thread to exit the app.  The terminating app can then open the event object by name using [`EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433b98s3.aspx), and then signal the event with [`EventWaitHandle.Set()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set).